# How delete duplicated and minor size files in a dir

Tags: windows, batch-file, duplicates, size

### i have few million files in one single dir:

*size 07kb* - "johnny.zip"

*size 57kb* - "johnny (1).zip"

*size 13kb* - "johnny (2).zip"

*size 12kb* - "dhick.zip"

*size 11kb* - "dhick (5).zip"

*size 34kb* - "dhick (8).zip"

---

**i want to keep only the single largest file for each name found.
Eliminating all the other smaller and duplicate ones, in this case:**

---

*size 07kb* - "johnny.zip"     <<< DELETE THIS! (because duplicate and smaller in size)

***size 57kb* - "johnny (1).zip"** *do nothing...*

*size 13kb* - "johnny (2).zip" <<< DELETE THIS! (because duplicate and smaller in size)

*size 12kb* - "dick.zip"       <<< DELETE THIS! (because duplicate and smaller in size)

*size 11kb* - "dick (5).zip"   <<< DELETE THIS! (because duplicate and smaller in size)

***size 34kb* - "dick (8).zip"** *do nothing...*

---

### How can i do please?

Comment: It is a little bit unclear for me what should be deleted. From the examples it looks like you want only to delete the small files - e.g. under 30kb. But I'm not even sure what should be considered as a little file. Or you want to keep only the biggest file with the similar name?

Comment: Hello @npocmaka i want to keep only the single largest file for each name found.
Eliminating all the other smaller and duplicate ones.

Comment: What if there is no "single largest file"? What if the files are the same size? How are you going to decide which one to keep? Keep the youngest? Sort by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%A in (*.zip) do (
    for /f "eol=| delims=(" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        set "string=%%~B"
        call :trim

        for /f "skip=1 eol=| delims=" %%C in (
            'call dir /b /o-s "%%string%%*.zip"'
        ) do (
            del "%%~C"
        )
    )
)

exit /b

:trim
if "%string:~-1%" == " " set "string=%string:~0,-1%" & goto :trim
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ("%string%") do set "string=%%~A"
exit /b 0
```

This is how I would try to achieve the task. Being a few million files is large so trying to do it all in memory with sorting etc. could be difficult. What this tries to do is to iterate a file, get the base name (*the string before any closing parentheses*) and to append `*.zip` to get files sorted and remove the smaller files and leaving just the largest file. Hopefully you do not have too many of one base name i.e. `johnny`.

While I have done some simple tests, this is not thoroughly proven without a doubt. It might be safer to use `ren` instead of `del`, e.g: `ren "%%~C" "%%~nC.bak"`. If something is not correct, use `ren *.bak *.zip` to undo. If correct `del *.bak`. Test on a small group of copied files to ensure it works as expected. I state this as `del` cannot be undone.

The `dir /b /o-s` will sort by size (*largest 1st*) so just need to `skip 1` and delete the rest. The `call` is used to expand `%%string%%` so no use of delayed expansion is used. The label `:trim` removes spaces at either end of the string
which is present after delimiting by `(`, so the space needs removal for the wildcard search to work correct.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and practical solution. It solved the problem perfectly by eliminating duplicate files and with the smaller size.
I adopted the RENAME technique and only afterwards I deleted the found and renamed files.
Greetings friend and thank you for your collaboration. If I can, I will return the favor.